# LINQ to SQL dynamically select column in SqlMethods.Like() where condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to dynamically select which column this runs on? I don't need the comparison, just the column dynamically selected.

```
where SqlMethods.Like(s.GradeLevel, grade)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up the query dynamically using the Expression. Here's an example I wrote to be able to dymically choose colums to filter.

```
private static Expression GetStringCompareExpression<TEntity>(Expression parameters, string method, FilterContainer filter, Type type)
{
    Expression expression;
    MemberExpression field = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameters, filter.field);
    Expression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.value.ToLower().Trim(), type);
    Expression lowercase = Expression.Call(field, "ToLower", null, null);
    Expression trim = Expression.Call(lowercase, "Trim", null, null);
    expression = AddNotNullExpression(field, Expression.Call(trim, method, null, constant));
    return expression;
}
```

This one does the following:

- Creates a field expression
- Creates constant expression (the value to compare in this case)
- Creates a call expression to call the ToLower() on the value in the expression
- Creates a call expression to call the Trim() on the value in the expression
- The 'AddNotNullExpression' add a test for 'not null' for the value
- It returns the expression

Here's the 'AddNotNullExpression' method:

```
private static Expression AddNotNullExpression(MemberExpression field, Expression expression)
{
    if(field.Type.IsNullable())
    {
        // String mag niet null zijn
        Expression nullConstant = Expression.Constant(null, field.Type);
        Expression notNull = Expression.NotEqual(field, nullConstant);
        expression = Expression.AndAlso(notNull, expression);
    }

    return expression;
}
```

Call it like so:

```
Expression  expression = GetStringCompareExpression<TEntity>(parameters, "Contains", filter, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
```

And finally return the IQueryable<> like so:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Where<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, FilterContainer filters)
{
    Expression expression = GetSingleExpression<TEntity>(filters, parameters);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expression, parameters);

    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

It is not completely what you ask because this one was written to translate a filter expression coming from a grid in the view (which is in the FilterContainer) but it gives an idea on how you can write your 'Like' yourself

Answer (score 0):

If your "dynamically" depends on a certain condition, they yes. Build your linq query without this condition first. Then add if statements and add appropriate condition.

```
var query = ....;
if (value1 = condition1) {
 query = from q in query
         where SqlMethods.Like(s.GradeLevel, grade);
}

if (value2 == condition2) {
 query = from q in query
         where SqlMethods.Like(s.Name, name);
}
```

The query will be build on the very last possible moment, not in advance, so you can safely use this approach.